# Matrix determinant query

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $\{v_1,v_2, ..., v_n \}$ be an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ where the determinant of the matrix with columns, $v_1, ..., v_n$ is $+1$. Let $x_1 = v_1$ and $x_i = $ (linear combination of $v_1,..., v_{i-1}$) $ + a_iv_i.$ Is it true (and why!) that $\det(x_1,x_2, ...,x_n) =\det(v_1,a_2v_2, ..., a_nv_n) = 1 \times a_2 \times \cdot \cdot \cdot \times a_n.$ Is it something to do with an upper triangular matrix?

Edit:

Let $X = (v_1, ..., v_n) $ be a matrix be a matrix with columns, $v_1,...,v_n$ and similarly define the matrix $Y = (v_1,a_2v_2 ..., a_nv_n).$ Then $X^TY$ is a matrix with main diagonal elements $1,a_2,..,a_n$ and non-main diagonal elements equal to zero. Thus the det($X^TY$) = $1 \times a_2 \times \cdot \cdot \cdot \times a_n$. Since $\det(X^T) = 1$, this implies that $\det(Y)= 1 \times a_2 \times \cdot \cdot \cdot \times a_n.$ Is this correct? Still don't know how to prove/disprove the part $\det(x_1,x_2, ...,x_n) =\det(v_1,a_2v_2, ..., a_nv_n).$

Comment: Can you think of any ideas why it might or might not be true?

Comment: @SuzuHirose Any hints? :)

Comment: It doesn't involve upper triangular matrices. The result follows from two of the basic properties of determinants, so if you google for "properties of determinants" you should be able to find it out. For example [this page](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Linear_Algebra/A_First_Course_in_Linear_Algebra_(Kuttler)/03%3A_Determinants/3.02%3A_Properties_of_Determinants) has everything you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only two basic properties of determinants need be known.

First, if one multiplies any column of a matrix by a scalar, the determinant of the resulting matrix is the determinant of the original matrix multiplied by that scalar.
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
a_{11} & ... & \alpha a_{1j} & ... & a_{1n}\\
a_{21} & ... &\alpha a_{2j} & ... & a_{2n}\\
a_{31} & ... &\alpha a_{3j} & ... & a_{3n}\\
\vdots \\
a_{n1} & ... &\alpha a_{nj} & ... & a_{nn}\\
\end{vmatrix}=
\alpha
\begin{vmatrix}
a_{11} & ... &a_{1j} & ... & a_{1n}\\
a_{21} & ... &a_{2j} & ... & a_{2n}\\
a_{31} & ... &a_{3j} & ... & a_{3n}\\
\vdots \\
a_{n1} & ... &a_{nj} & ... & a_{nn}\\
\end{vmatrix}
$$
This is obvious from the definition of determinants.

Second, if one adds any column to another column, the determinant of the resulting matrix is the same as that of the original matrix.
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
a_{11} & ... & a_{1j} + a_{1k} & ... & a_{1n}\\
a_{21} & ... & a_{2j} + a_{2k}& ... & a_{2n}\\
a_{31} & ... & a_{3j} + a_{3k}& ... & a_{3n}\\
\vdots \\
a_{n1} & ... & a_{nj} + a_{nk} & ... & a_{nn}\\
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
a_{11} & ... &a_{1j} & ... & a_{1n}\\
a_{21} & ... &a_{2j} & ... & a_{2n}\\
a_{31} & ... &a_{3j} & ... & a_{3n}\\
\vdots \\
a_{n1} & ... &a_{nj} & ... & a_{nn}\\
\end{vmatrix}
$$
Because the additional column $k$ part in column $j$ is not linearly independent of the other columns, its contribution vanishes.